# spring boot Can not @Autowired dao

Tags: spring-boot

I met a question , I try to startup project,bu it's failed

These are my configuration ,dao  and service , is anyone can tell me why ,thx a lot

This is DataBaseConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataBaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataBaseConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment env) {
        this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(env, "dataSource.");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        log.debug("Configuring DataSource");

        DruidDataSource druidDataSource = new DruidDataSource();
        druidDataSource.setUrl(propertyResolver.getProperty("url"));
        druidDataSource.setDriverClassName(propertyResolver.getProperty("driverClassName"));
        druidDataSource.setUsername(propertyResolver.getProperty("username"));
        druidDataSource.setPassword(propertyResolver.getProperty("password"));

        return druidDataSource;
    }
}
```

This is MybatisConfiguration  :

```
    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnClass({ EnableTransactionManagement.class,    EntityManager.class})
    @AutoConfigureAfter({ DataBaseConfiguration.class })
    @MapperScan("com.future.api.**.dao")
    public class MybatisConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

        private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MybatisConfiguration.class);

        private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Override
        public void setEnvironment(Environment env) {
            this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(env, "mybatis.");
        }

        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean
        public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() {
            try {
                SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
                sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
                sessionFactory.setTypeAliasesPackage(propertyResolver
                        .getProperty("typeAliasesPackage"));
                sessionFactory
                        .setMapperLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
                                .getResources(propertyResolver
                                        .getProperty("mapperLocations")));
                sessionFactory
                        .setConfigLocation(new DefaultResourceLoader()
                                .getResource(propertyResolver
                                        .getProperty("configLocation")));
                return sessionFactory.getObject();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.warn("Could not configure mybatis session factory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean
        public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        }
    }
```

This is dao

```
 public interface UserMapper extends BaseDao<User,UserCriteria ,String> {
        @SelectProvider(type=UserSqlProvider.class, method="countByExample")
        int countByExample(UserCriteria example);

        @DeleteProvider(type=UserSqlProvider.class, method="deleteByExample")
        int deleteByExample(UserCriteria example);

        @Delete({
            "delete from t_user",
            "where id = #{id,jdbcType=VARCHAR}"
        })
        int deleteByPrimaryKey(String id);

        @Insert({
            "insert into t_user (id, username, ",
            "password, created_by, ",
            "created_date, last_modified_by, ",
            "last_modified_date)",
            "values (#{id,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{username,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, ",
            "#{password,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{createdBy,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, ",
            "#{createdDate,jdbcType=DATE}, #{lastModifiedBy,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, ",
            "#{lastModifiedDate,jdbcType=DATE})"
        })
        int insert(User record);
    }
```

This is service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImp extends BaseServiceImpl<User,UserCriteria> implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userDao;

    @Override
    protected BaseDao<User, UserCriteria, String> getDao() {
        return userDao;
    }
}
```

This error info

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.future.api.user.dao.UserMapper com.future.api.user.service.imp.UserServiceImp.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.future.api.user.dao.UserMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.future.api.user.dao.UserMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please remove the images and add the *full* stack trace not only a snippet. And for starters I suggest you remove your config classes and use the Spring Boot provided datasource (why add another layer of complexity) and use the mybatis spring boot starter instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: Sorry , I don't understand what's you mean .....

Comment: What don't you understand? Spring Boot already has a datasource configuration, why try to add your own. MyBatis has already auto config support itself, why add your own...

Comment: Oh , I will try it , thx so much .

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem may be this annotation:

```
@MapperScan("com.future.api.**.dao")
```

I haven't seen before (in code as well as in documentation) that it would be possible to use wildcards. Try use exact package name.

I believe it scans also sub-packages, so you may want to change package structure to have all DAOs in tree under single package.

Comment: No , I have many modules below api ,If I use exact package name , the others will can't be scaned

Comment: I updated my answer. Other option would be to contribute wildcard feature to mybatis-spring project :). But you would need to talk to maintainers first if they want it.

Comment: Good suggestion , and i resolve the problem . It's caused by EntityManage.class in MybatisConfiguration ,but I don't know why . Thx again :)